# enable "inspect element" permanently

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, mouse

I want to activate "select element by mouse" permanently.
(this one.. how to make it to enable permanently? because after 1 click, it still deactivates) :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With FireBug I have found <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will enable inspect mode on the fly if you are good with keyboard shortcuts.

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Keyboard_and_Mouse_Shortcuts

If you use FireFox's Developer Console <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then after clicking on an element there is a box leftover with an Inspect icon